# Hiding secret key in webpack bundle.js from redux-persist-transform-encrypt

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I am using redux-persist in combination with redux-persist-transform-encrypt to encrypt my redux store in localstorage.  So I implemented the encryption like so:

```
const encryptor = createEncryptor({
    secretKey: 'my-super-secret-key',
    onError: function(error) {
      // Handle the error.
      console.log(error);
    }
}); 

const persistConfig: PersistConfig = {
    key: 'citizentracker',
    storage: storage,
    blacklist: new Array('form'),
    transforms: [encryptor]
};
```

Everything works well and the redux store is encrypted in local storage.  The issue I noticed is that when I do my production bundle via webpack 4.  In the bundle.js file you can see the key value by searching for "secretKey".  When I did I was able to see this:

```
{secretKey:"my-super-secret-key",onError:function(e){console.log(e)}}
```

Does anybody know of a way to generate a key to use for encryption, but also hide that key from people viewing the bundle.js in sources?  Or some other way of making this encryption more secure.

Comment: The key will be there no matter what. If nothing else, someone will place a breakpoint at the decryption call where the payload and key are passed in, and it's game over for you.

Comment: @AKX, Right thats what my understanding is as well.  If the javascript is bundled and minified though, users shouldnt be able to debug it right?  The answer I put below seems to help disguise the key being set, so somebody cant recognize the transform package and then look for the "secretKey" property and its corresponding value.

Comment: Minification and bundling definitely doesn't prevent debugging, it just makes it harder. A sufficiently interested attacker will be able to find the decryption key regardless of how you protect it.

Answer (score -1):

So one thing I went and explored the option of doing was to use `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` to use with webpack.  This allowed me to do object property name minification via the mangle property of the UglifyJsPlugin.  So in the following code, I told it to minify only the object property of "secretKey" via regex.  The secret in plain text will still exist in the bundle.js file, but at least now it will be harder to find.  Still exploring additional options.

This is the new webpack plugin added to the optimization property of the webpack config variable.

```
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          mangle: {
            properties: {
              regex: /secretKey/
            }
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  },
```

So the output into bundle.js would become:

```
{u:"my-super-secret-key",onError:function(e){console.log(e)}}
```

This helps but of course would like to hear better solutions!

Comment: any idea how to do this with the terser plugin, or have you found another way?